# JQuery - div fading trouble

Tags: jquery, effects, fading

I have div, which has id 'content'. It's visible.

```
<div id="wrapper" style="display:block">
  <div id="content">
    Some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to fade it out:

```
$('#wrapper').fadeIn( 1500 );
$('#content').click(function(){
   $(this).fadeOut( 1500 );
});
```

And nothing happens.
But when I wrote:

```
$('#content').fadeIn( 1500 );
```

It hides and then shows again.

---

Here is css

```
#content
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Browser: Firefox 3.5.3 under Linux Gentoo

**upd**

When I type code:

```
$('#content').hide();
```

It hides correctly.

---

**upd**

I've solved problem... I can't understand, why did it was... Just replaced jquery.min with jquery

Comment: Any chance you could post more code or link to a demo?

Comment: Probably is not the issue, but you've written "content" and "conent" :P

Can you share more of your CSS code for the div#content?

Comment: can you specify more information, such as the css style, if any, applied to that element and the browser version you are using, and whether you are using the jqueryui css styles on that page.

Comment: Any chance you're observing this on IE?

Comment: I've updated post. Sorry, but I'm not able to make demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you have two problems: the content doesn't fade in, and when you click it, the content doesn't fade out.

Both problems are probably caused by your script executing before the wrapper and content divs have appeared in the document. If your `<script>` tag is in the `<head>` of your document, then `$('#wrapper')` won't find anything to fade in and `$('#content')` won't find anything to attach a click handler to.

The best solution is probably to defer doing anything until the document is loaded, by using `ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#wrapper').fadeIn(1500);
  $('#content').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(1500);
  });
});
```

Alternatively you could put your `<script>` tag *after* the `<div>` tags in the body.

When you fix this problem the content will fade in, but it won't be smooth because the wrapper div is initially visible—you have `style="display:block"` on the wrapper div. You need to make that `display: none;` instead so that the wrapper div is hidden while the page is loading.

Here is a complete file which works:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper
{
    display: none;
}

#content
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">
  window.alert("Couldn't load jQuery");
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#wrapper').fadeIn(1500);
  $('#content').click(function () {
     $(this).fadeOut(1500);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    Some text
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've solved my problem. I can't copy all code, cause it's too big and has it's own dependings. But I'll make your post as answer on my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, firefox on OSX.  Make sure that your id's are unique, if you have a duplicate it might not work right.   Also, your style: block is redundant, divs are blocks by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrote $('#content') in the fadeOut and $('#conent') in the fadeIn. Other that this the effects are being called exactly the same way and offer no explanation as to why they wouldn't both be working as expected.

Comment: Sorry, it was my type-mistake.

Comment: Ockonal, I setup a test with the code you supplied (copy/paste) and it worked fine in Windows XP Firefox 3.5 and IE 8 if that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

You are also leaving a # out in "#wrapper" (line 1 of jQuery).